# why I got less records with spark reading data from Hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, pyspark

I'm using spark(code in python) to read data from Hbase table, I have 200K records in Hbase, but Spark only read 138 records out. I double checked my code  but still not be able to find the problem. I'd like to copy the snippet code here please:

```
 confRead = {
            "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "196.0.0.2:2181",
            "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "testTable",
            "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns":"cf1:raw64"
            }

 keyConvRead = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
 valueConvRead = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

 hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConvRead,
        valueConverter=valueConvRead,
        conf=confRead)
 hbaseRDD = hbase_rdd.map(download_Analize)
```

Need to mention that the column raw64 is really big about 1M-20M bytes and it's encoded in base64, and also some other small columns in the same column family cf1, actually I only have on column family. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `"hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns":"cf1:raw64"` possibly this is only giving you the rows that have raw64 qualifier? you can check that in your hbase to confirm.